# when call the contract method in node.js app, got invalid JSON RPC response: {"size":0,"timeout":0}

Tags: web3js

```
    const web3 = new Web3(PROVIDER);
    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
    const data = await ctrt.methods.myMethod(account).call();
```

When i request with my method, it got error `Invalid JSON RPC response: {"size":0,"timeout":0}`.

Thanks a lot if you can help.

Comment: I have the same issue. very strange as the function succeeds but at the same time gives this error! did you ever find out why?

Comment: Yeah, it it solved. It is actually network issue in local. I am using VPN, but seems it does not configure well. So it might not be a classic issue.